# Why is there two different CSS attribute selector namely, [att|=val],[att^=val] selector for same work?

Tags: css

From [w3c.org](http://www.w3c.org), these two CSS attribute selectors:

- `[att|=val]`
- `[att^=val]`

search for attribute value which starts with val or exactly val.

If I am right why, is there two different selector for the same work?

What is the difference between those two selectors?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: “Starts with” and “is exactly” are two completely different things, isn’t that obvious? Your name is `Mohiuddin` – and `Mohiuddinwhoasksweirdquestions` _starts_ with the same, but it _is_ not the same now, is it?

Comment: okay, but "Mohiuddin" and "Mohiuddinwhoasksweirdquestions" both  word start with "Mohiuddin". if val = "Mohiuddin" , should not both the words are matched for [att|=val] and [att^=val]? @CBroe

Comment: The two selector types do not do “the same work”. The difference is obvious from CSS specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't come up with an attribute value that `|=` matches that `^=` does not.  The [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) say

> [att|=val]
>   Represents an element with the att attribute, its value either being exactly "val" or beginning with "val" immediately followed by "-" (U+002D). This is primarily intended to allow language subcode matches (e.g., the hreflang attribute on the a element in HTML) as described in BCP 47 ([BCP47]) or its successor. For lang (or xml:lang) language subcode matching, please see the :lang pseudo-class.

So it seems like `|=` was developed for a specific purpose.  You would want to use it in cases where you want to match `val-` but not `value`.

[|= existed in selectors level 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors).  `^=` did not.

Comment: They are different selectors. Neither supersedes the other.

Answer (score 3):

They both work the same, but `att|=val` was developed to select something like language codes or if you're following the naming convention where you split words with `-` (e.g. `simple-attribute-name`), you can make sure just to select the part you're looking for.

An example where both won't work the same:

You have 2 elements:

```
<span att="simple-attribute-name">
<span att="simpleattributename">
```

- `att|="simple"` will match the first span element, but won't match the second one, because `simple` is not followed by a `-`.
- `att^="simple"` will match both elements, because both `att` values start with `simple`.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maremp/DGF48/1/) shows an example that this works:

- `att^="simple"` makes both texts bold **but**
- `att|="simple"` selects only first text and makes it red.